# How to send form values using JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to process a form that utilizes a multi select plugin http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#faq

that stores multiple select drop down values in a variable, but I can't figure out how to send to php along with the rest of the form data.

Here is the form:

```
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="sr-only" for="">Zip Code</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" name="zip"  id="zip">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 sr-only control-label">Products</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="product" multiple>
          <!-- <option value="selected">Select Products</option> -->
          <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
          <option value="Motorcycle/ATV">Motorcycle/ATV</option>
          <option value="Boat/PWC">Boat/PWC</option>
          <option value="Motor Home">Motor Home</option>
          <option value="Travel Trailer">Travel Trailer</option>
          <option value="Snowmobile">Snowmobile</option>
          <option value="Commercial Auto">Commercial Auto</option>
          <option value="Homeowners">Homeowners</option>
          <option value="Condo">Condo</option>
          <option value="Renters">Renters</option>
          <option value="Mobile Home">Mobile Home</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <button id="next1" class="btn btn-orange" type="submit" >Get Quote</button>

  </form>
```

The way the plugin works is that it saves the multiple items in the select drop down as an array and can be accessed with

```
 var products = validator.getFieldElements('product').val();
```

I know it's storing all the values properly because I can see the values if I place the products variable above in a alert statement.

Here is the ajax request along with the variable I need to add to ajax data param

```
    var products = validator.getFieldElements('product').val();
    alert(products);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process-step1.php",
      data: $('.home1').serialize(),
      success: function(msg){

          // alert("made it to success block!");
          alert(msg);

          document.location.href = 'form.php';


      },
      error: function(){
        alert("error");
      }
    });//close ajax
```

Can someone please show me how to package that with the rest of the form and send over to php using the ajax?

On the php side I'm using the following to grab the post variables, but as is I'm only getting the last value stored in the products variable

```
 if(isset($_POST['zip']) && isset($_POST['product'])){
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
    …
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional data along with the serialize..

data: ($('.home1').serialize(), products: products),

I believe that will support arrays as well.

Comment: When I tried that I'm getting the following error:SyntaxError: Expected token ')'.  Here is a link to the site http://aaronhaas.com/bsi10/index.html

Comment: my syntax may be wrong .. try {} instead of () around the data set (data: {stuff},) .. sorry

Comment: thanks again, but I'm still getting an error with 

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "process-step1.php",
          data: {$('.home1').serialize(), products: products},
          success: function(msg){
              alert(msg);        
              document.location.href = 'form.php'; 
          },
          error: function(){
            alert("error");
          }
        });//close ajax

Comment: I'll try it out and see what the proper syntax is... I'll get back to you